# C# .NET Windows Forms Block/Supress Upload Files in Webbrowser Component

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, upload, browser

Is there any way to block uploading files (any file) from a website accessed by a component webbrowser (C#)? I've been trying several ways but nothing works...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you tried anything so far? Show your effort first.. Plesae read [FAQ] and [ask] also..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any easy or difficult way of acheiving this as the openFileDialog is called automatically by the MSHTML.dll upon clicking on the html input file field. There isn't any interface, method or property that can programmatically override or prevent the dialog from opening.

I've found an approach I think would work for this case. What you need to do is to identify every HTTP header that includes "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" via the "WebBrowser.Navigating" event, as this is used every time a file is about to stream from the local computer to the server. Then you could cancel the data stream immediately.

Comment: the only problem with this solution is: there isn't restriction to the files on hard disk. I need a solution that do something one step before...

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem!

the solution was: hide the dialog box! I used the object id (window id) to find the dialog box. It's the only way to "block" any dialog box!

see the code below:

```
    // P/Invoke declarations
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string id, string caption);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

    public void Execute()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("#32770", null);

        if (!hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0010, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

I hope this solution helps other users!